# if i use redis cache, will data be stored in RAM? or will it fetch from locally stored database file

Tags: php, mongodb, caching, yii, redis

I am planning to implement certain level of caching in a an **PHP application which uses Yii** framework, for performance issues i need to ***implement multilevel caching***, for which i have come to conclusion; use redis.

but since all my ***data is currently in mongodb,*** so i am not sure, whether storing same set of data in redis and later querying it, will *

> make equally expensive db calls, or certain set of data will be stored
>   in Cache/RAM/Hard disk hierarchy ??

*

Comment: @RyanBabu : yeah, so it will be on RAM only, from there onward i guess its up to the Os to use Cache memory.

Comment: No, prevent swapping at all times. Redis is not designed for that. If you need disk-based, don't use Redis, but for example Aerospike (not free, but good). If you don't mind experimental, you could look into the [ardb redis fork](https://github.com/yinqiwen/ardb)

Comment: @TwBert : m not looking for disk based, i m looking for performance improvements by keeping some data in RAM, 
So, u say, i have to manage swapping of RAM contents by myself?

Comment: As already said, redis is all-RAM. Choose hardware with enough RAM for the complete redis db. (Cloud-) hardware with for example 250GB of RAM is not uncommon (if you need it). To scale beyond that, shard your data. Don't rely on swapping. Don't use redis if your requirements are different.